# Laravel, additional request data

Tags: php, laravel

Im sending from my form 2 values - title and content.
MySQL table has fields: id, title, content, userID, created_at, updated_at. Table was created with laravel migration. I dont have to send id, created_at and updated_at. Only title, content and userID which I get from Auth::class.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    //some validation
    $request->request->add(['userID' => Auth::id()]);
    Article::create($request->all());

    // testing purpose
    return $request->all();
}
```

I know I can do it another way directly in create function using array_merge or simply adding two arrays, but **I thought this is better way (?)** to do this, but Im getting such error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'userID' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `articles` (`title`, `content`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ...
```

Looks like function create doesnt't see `userID` value. What is funny, if I comment that `create` line, by return I can see in my brower everything:

```
{"_token":"...","title":"Test","content":"Test","userID":1}
```

Why is it returned correctly and in same time function `create` doesn't see `userID` value?

Comment: Why laravel builds SQL query without userID field/value, when its passed with request object...

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the request body instead: `Article::create($request->request->all);`

It looks like there might be an error with parsing that added value.

Also, when you call `$request->request->all()`, does it have your added `userID`?

Comment: Thanks Martin for your answer.

Passing request body `Article::create($request->request->all());` did not help. Same error.

Same time, when I `return $request->request->all()` - yest, I do have `userID` in request array.

`{"_token":"...","title":"Test","content":"Test","userID":"1"}`

Honestly... strange.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your further explanation! As you say, it sure is strange, I think that it might be an issue how Eloquent hydrates the model object. Maybe merging two arrays might be a better approach in the end.

Comment: Already found a solution. Sometimes its so simple, that you spend literally hours and can't find it... The problem was indeed with Eloquent, with $fillable parameter... First version was without userID which I added later... This is why query was build without userID.

But thanks for your efforts.

Comment: No problems, I'm glad you resolved the issue. I wouldn't think of guarded properties neither on the first thought.